# Run linux java applications

Tags: java, linux, desktop-application, desktop, launcher

So, my goal is to have a .desktop analyze it and start the program, the part where I extract the information from the .desktop I have already done, the problem is to start the applications, if I do

Desktop.getDesktop (). Open (file);

obviously it opens it to me with the system launcher, which I don't want, I wanted to know if there are any libraries that recognize the file and try to run it with the correct software (Appimage, jar and others are a problem, if not I could just do sh "path")

Answer (score 1):

The .desktop file should point to a shell script which calls java on the needed application, or run java directly on the needed application (I guess it's a jar file).

```
java -classpath <classpath> -jar <path_to_your_jar>
```

Comment: I don't want to run my java program through a .desktop, I want to run the apps that are in the .desktop, the problem is that many use extensions like .AppImage

example:

[Desktop Entry]
Name = Tiled
GenericName = Map Editor
Comment = Tile Map Editor
TryExec = / home / gattolfo / Applications / Tiled-1.8.4-x86_64_45370181d608e5498c38076f1821f989.AppImage
Exec = / home / gattolfo / Applications / Tiled-1.8.4-x86_64_45370181d608e5498c38076f1821f989.AppImage% F
Terminal = false
Type = Application

Comment: my bad, I didn't fully understand the question in the first place. you can use `file -i <your_file>` in order to check the mimetype for the given file, then take an appropriate action for every mimetype (maybe a case statement in the bash script which decides with which application the file should be openened)

Comment: Oh cool, this is a very good idea